# How to Change Decimal Separator in Eclipse Settings

Tags: eclipse, format

I need to change the decimal separator from `,` to `.`.

I do not want to write code for this each time, which is suggested everywhere. Is there a setting for this in Eclipse?

I have already changed it from Control Panel -> Regional Options in Windows 8.1

For instance, `Vector3d.toString()` appears as `Vector3d[70,49,52,81,45,58]`, which is confusing. I want it to be `Vector3d[70.49,52.81,45.58]`

Comment: Change it for what? Some program you are writing? Which language?

Comment: While writing to file, I want decimal separators as dots because I'll use that file in to plot using gnuplot afterwards.